# Menu in immersion for glass ware development

Tags: android-studio, google-glass

I am quite new in android developing, I would like to develop an application for google glass when I create a new project and choosing immersion as a user interface no menu and layout appear in the left column of the android studio under "Android" option in "res" directory. How can I have these two files there? thnx!